# apache phoenix installation on cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am facing problem with installing apache phoenix on cloudera. I refered http://crazyadmins.com/install-and-configure-apache-phoenix-on-cloudera-hadoop-cdh5/ and many other with the same approach. 
My cloudera version is 5.5. I'm getting errors onn running the command:

```
./psql.py <hostname/localhost/IP>:2181 ../examples/WEB_STAT.sql ../examples/WEB_STAT.csv ../examples/WEB_STAT_QUERIES.sql 

org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:Fri Jan 05 16:09:08 IST 2018,RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1515148748159, pause=100, retries=35}.
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
```

Comment: and also where to RUN (psql.py & sqlline.py) this command on namenode or datanode

Comment: it says Can't get master address from ZooKeeper znode data == null 
i'm running following command ./sqlline.py ip-address:2181:/hbase:username@kerberos_principal:/home/admin/kerberos_keytab

Comment: and hbase master is running it cloudera manager it shows active

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect to hbase?  From the error message it seems that it is not up.

As for sqlline, you can run it anywhere as long as you point it to the namenode.

Comment: yeah hbase is working... Master is Active all region servers are active.

Comment: did you drop the phoenix-server jar on every node? under the /hbase/lib directory and restart?

Comment: what i did is I downloaded parcel from https://archive.cloudera.com/cloudera-labs/phoenix/parcels/ and added that parcel file in parcel-repo directory of cloudera , on adding it shown clas_phoenix in parcel tab of host in cloudera manager from their i distributed it and activated it.  This steps i followed https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/11/new-apache-phoenix-4-5-2-package-from-cloudera-labs/

Comment: Have you fixed this issue I need to install it as well.